# When is it allowed to combine two samples?

Tags: sampling, experiment-design, survey, meta-analysis

I have two samples (from two experiments) with different variances, and I want to combine these two samples with a factor (`1` and `2` for each experiment), and then maybe do a multilevel multivariate analysis.

Where can I find literature on the issue of whether I am allowed to combine these two samples with a factor?

Or, is it better to do the analysis separately and do a meta-analysis on the results?

Comment: The two approaches you mention can help you answer somewhat (or very) different questions.  What research question(s) do you want to answer?

Comment: thanks for your reply. I want to find out if my single independent variable has a significant effect on any of my dependent variables (20 Items from the suervey (multivariate) and if yes in which direction.

Comment: Your terms don't seem consistent. A survey usually rules out an experiment and vice-versa. Why do you think you have two experiments with survey samples?

Comment: I used the wrong terminology probably. What I meant is I have two experiments, where my participants answered the same questionnaire  (survey) handed to them.

Answer (score 2):

If your questionnaire instruments are the same and the two interventions are the same then pool the two samples and test each item for the two treatment groups.

You can obtain additional information to evaluate the similarity of the two groups. For example, you can include a term in your analysis for group or sample. If these are substantially different then you can conclude that one sample gives different answers, higher or lower. This doesn't mean you shouldn't pool the samples, only that you might report it. You might also examine the covariance matrices of the two samples. Again, being different doesn't mean you shouldn't pool the two samples.

You don't really have a sample survey of the population, as the term is usually used where the sampling uses complex methods such as stratification, cluster samples, unequal probabilities, etc. There is a large literature on how to combine two or more such samples for analysis, but you don't need that.

Even if your two samples are significantly different in some dimensions I would still pool them. They could differ for a number of unimportant reasons.

I think I would do all my analyses in a consistent way, either with a term in the model for the sample, or not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yess, the questionnaire instruments were the same but the problem is that I don't have the same sample size in the two experiments. In the first experiment I have 14 participants and in the second one I have 12 participants so I had the problem of missing data on the second experiment therefore I decided to do a Multilevel analysis although the intraclass correlation on a level that I am planning to use is small.

Comment: You don't need equal sample sizes from the two experiments.

Comment: Are the same people in each experiment except for two missing?

Comment: I assumed the respondents were different in my answer.

Comment: No the participants are not the same. they were different people for each experiment.

Comment: @David  Smith : can you please refer me to the literature you know on this issue "here is a large literature on how to combine two or more such samples for analysis, but you don't need that."     thanks in advance!

Comment: This is now fairly common for large surveys. Usually the methods depend on the specific survey, eg, National Health Interview Survey, National Health and Nutrition Examination Survey, etc. I would start with the web sites for such surveys and recent Proceedings of the Survey Section of the American Statistical Association.